# Object as a property of a Class

Tags: swift, class, oop

I have a class named Person with some properties that I initialize when creating the exemplar of its class. Like name and surname.

What if my person will have a husband with the same props as Person?

For example:

```
class Person {
    let name: String
    let surname: String
    let husband: Person? //here's the problem

    init(name: String, surname: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
    }
}
```

Can I do something like that in Swift language?

so initialization will look like this: `let p1 = Person(name: Anna, surname: "Jehnis", husband: (name: "John", suname: "Williams"))`

or I'm misunderstanding the OOP completely?

Comment: Where is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem with OOP, you understand it correctly. However, you are missing one point. A marriage goes in both directions. Therefore if you want to do it correctly:

```
class Person {
    let name: String
    let surname: String
    // make it weak to prevent reference cycles
    weak var lifePartner: Person?

    init(name: String, surname: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
    }
}


let person1 = Person(name: "Anna", surname: "Jehnis")
let person2 = Person(name: "John", surname: "Williams")

person1.lifePartner = person2
person2.lifePartner = person1
```

which of course, could be put into a method:

```
class Person {
   ...

   func marry(partner: Person) {
      lifePartner = partner
      partner.lifePartner = self
   }
}

let person1 = Person(name: "Anna", surname: "Jehnis")
let person2 = Person(name: "John", surname: "Williams")
person1.marry(person2)
```